# Calling Another Powershell Script With A Timeout

Tags: powershell

I have this function:

```
function getHDriveSize($usersHomeDirectory)
{
    $timeOutSeconds = 600
    $code = 
    {
        $hDriveSize = powershell.exe $script:getHDriveSizePath - path $usersDirectory
        return $hDriveSize
    }

    $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $code

    if (Wait-Job $job -Timeout $timeOutSeconds)
    {
        $receivedJob = Receive-Job $job
        return $receivedJob
    }
    else
    {
        return "Timed Out"
    }
}
```

When I call it, I get a `CommandNotFoundException`:

```
-path : The term '-path' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

However, the line:

```
$hDriveSize = powershell.exe $script:getHDriveSizePath - path $usersDirectory
```

by itself works fine.

How can I call the powershell script within the $code variable successfully?

Comment: First of all, `- path` cannot work. Second, it appears that `$script:getHDriveSizePath` seems to not exist, so PowerShell just gets an empty string there and tries executing `-path`. Third, your function name is way off and should probably be something like `Get-HDriveSize` instead.

Comment: @Joey That's probably just a typo, because the output would be different otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables and functions defined outside the scriptblock are not available inside the scriptblock. Because of this, both `$script:getHDriveSizePath` and `$usersDirectory` inside the scriptblock are `$null`, so that you're actually trying to run the statement `powershell.exe -Path`, which produces the error you observed. You need to pass variables as parameters into the scriptblock:

```psh
function getHDriveSize($usersHomeDirectory) {
  $timeOutSeconds = 600

  $code = {
    & powershell.exe $args[0] -Path $args[1]
  }

  $job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $code -ArgumentList $script:getHDriveSizePath, $usersHomeDirectory

  if (Wait-Job $job -Timeout $timeOutSeconds) {
    Receive-Job $job
  } else {
    'Timed Out'
  }
}
```